# 'Reverse Engineer' Model-First - Removal of table and column prefixes

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6

I am developing an EF Model from an existing database by using the 'reverse engineer' Model-First feature of VS2013 update 3. Unfortunately I do not have complete control of the database schema, which uses table and column prefixes (e.g. tblPerson, cFirstName, cLastName). If possible, I would prefer not to have these prefixes replicated to my model classes and properties. Is there easy to facilitate this 'removal' of prefixes whenever the model is regenerated with EF6, or am I going to end up writing a lot of code and using a Byzantine regeneration process to achieve this?

Comment: I don't know if there's a programmatic way to do it, but I've had to do this before by just editing the model after it's generated (either through the GUI or directly in the XML)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I settled on solving this problem was to use T4 templates. I was keen on using the 'reverse engineer Code-First from database' option now available in VS2013. What was less clear is that you can use T4 templates to modify the generated code. The missing step is the installation and modification of the default T4 templates using the package manager console - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn753860

So you basically end up with something like this in your T4 template (rough code for illustration purposes only):

```
var charsToTrim = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToCharArray();
var className = code.Type(entityType).ToString().TrimStart(charsToTrim);
```